# How to perform auto-increment inside db-select? (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I tried this method below but its not working.

```
$row = 0;
$record = DB::table('users')
  ->select(
    DB::raw("{{ $row++ }} AS no"),
    'users.name AS name'
  )
  ->get();
```

I just wish these **output** below:

```
|no|  Name   |
|1 | sample1 |
|2 | sample2 |
|3 | sample3 |
```

Been searching for the right syntax, but end nothing. Somebody knows how to do this. Thanks in adv.

---

### [Problem Solved] Another Solution I found aside of the Marked Answer below.

Here is my code:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw("SET @row = '0'"));
$record = DB::table('users')
  ->select(
    DB::raw("@row:=@row+1 AS no"),
    'name'
  )->get();
```

Comment: What is the # actually? Id number?

Comment: no Sir. it is not the id number from user-table. I just want to display a number on each value.

Comment: Is anything coming from your query?

Comment: "name" column displays. But "no" column displays null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for this situation you can simply add the "no" on PHP side:

```
$record = DB::table('users')
    ->select('users.name AS name')
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($row, $index) {
        $row->no = $index + 1;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

```
$record = DB::table('users')
       ->select(DB::raw('count(name) as No, name'))
       ->groupBy('name')
       ->orderBy('name','DESC')
       ->get();
```

First, you can count all users using `count(name)`
Then you can print in Descending order.

Comment: Sir it does not increment. Value of "no" column are all 1.

Comment: Can you give me the output of dd($record)

Comment: #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#515 ▼
      +"No": 1
      +"name": "Rubel"
    }
    1 => {#516 ▼
      +"No": 2
      +"name": "Nafeeur Rahman"
    }
  ]

Comment: It is coming to me. Please check it carefully.

Comment: All values in "no" column are all 1 Sir.

Comment: Heres my actual code..  $optr = DB::table('users')
          ->select(DB::raw('count(users.name) as No, users.name AS name'))
         ->groupBy('users.name')
         ->orderBy('users.name','DESC')
         ->get();

Comment: I tried these codes also but same result:  $optr = DB::table('users')
          ->select(DB::raw('count(name) as No, name'))
         ->groupBy('name')
         ->orderBy('name','DESC')
         ->get();

Comment: Heres result: [{"No":1,"name":"walter huel"},{"No":1,"name":"steve conroy dvm"},{"No":1,"name":"ruthe quitzon"},{"No":1,"name":"optodph"},{"No":1,"name":"mr. jonathan beatty phd"},{"No":1,"name":"liza roob"},{"No":1,"name":"laisha nicolas"},{"No":1,"name":"elinore robel dvm"},{"No":1,"name":"dr. yazmin mayert"},{"No":1,"name":"cecile gleichner"},{"No":1,"name":"audie schneider"}]